# Draw oval with option thickness in Android

Tags: android

I want to Draw an oval with option thickness

```
Paint paintt = new Paint();

paintt.setColor(Color.RED);

paintt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

RectF ovalBounds = new RectF(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy);

canvas.drawOval(ovalBounds, paintt);
```

If I want to increase the thickness of the oval , What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`setStrokeWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29) method on your paint.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setStrokeWidth()` method to draw an Oval with the option thickness.

e.g.:

```
paintt.setStrokeWidth(10); //thickness is 10, increase or decrease this value 10 accordingly
```